# Locating an event binding source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

We are building a site, and it has a ton of jQuery plugins and misc code from several developers.  Somewhere a keydown even was trapped by the document. (Basically the spacebar no longer has it's default browser usage, i.e. scrolling, selecting checkboxes, etc.)  Using Chrome's debugging tools, the origin is jquery-1.7.2.min.js line 3--  Not a lot of help.

I was able to "fix" the issue by running `$(document).off('keydown');` at the end of window.onload function, but I dislike this fix terribly.

Is there an *easy* way to find out where the original binding occurred?  (My guess is that some plugin defaults to "document" when not supplied with an element.) What I have done so far:

Grepped through the source for "keyCode" and removed any plugins that trap the spacebar. Removed other non-obvious plugins. I can continue with this, but I'm looking at a lot of grunt work.

Comment: Can you do a binary search through your plugins, enabling the first half only and seeing if you still have the issue, then the second half only, narrowing it down that way?  It's possible that it has to do with a combination of them, but that's much less likely, and this should be quick and would at least eliminate the individual plugins by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the developer tools in chrome, click inspect element on document's body element, scroll the right panel down to the bottom and view Event Listeners, it is probably attached to the body element or some other very big container. Check the listenerBody under the keydown event.